# Agregar fila desde un boton - datagridview c#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de agregar **1 fila desde un botón en mi datagridview en c#**,la información es cargada mediante diseño de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo para cargar informacion de una tabla de sql por datatable.

```js
public void mostrardatos() {

            dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text.Trim());

            foreach(DataRow data in dt.Rows){

                int aa = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[0].Value = data["ITEM"].ToString();
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[1].Value = data["para_cobranza"].ToString();
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[2].Value = data["NOMBRE_CONTACTO"].ToString();
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[3].Value = data["DIRECCION_CONTACTO"].ToString();
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[4].Value = data["TELEFONO_CONTACTO"].ToString();
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[5].Value = data["DNI"].ToString();

            }
        

        }
```

Alguna idea para agregar una fila desde el boton,facil puedo dejar la opcion editar o agregar desde el controlador del datagridview,pero en este caso quiero realizarlo desde el boton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pensaria en la siguiente adecuacion:

```
public void mostrardatos() {

        dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text.Trim());

        foreach(DataRow data in dt.Rows){

            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
          int aa=  this.dataGridView1.RowCount-1;/*Asi escribiras los datos en la ultima fila agregada al datagridview*/
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa ].Cells[0].Value = data["ITEM"].ToString();
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[1].Value = data["para_cobranza"].ToString();
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[2].Value = data["NOMBRE_CONTACTO"].ToString();
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[3].Value = data["DIRECCION_CONTACTO"].ToString();
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[4].Value = data["TELEFONO_CONTACTO"].ToString();
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[5].Value = data["DNI"].ToString();

        }
    

    }
```

Comment: este codigo funciono para mi  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); en el boton agregar,pero ahora tengo un problema adicional estoy queriendo guardar lo que se llena en esa fila y me encuentro que el checkbox se agrega solo cuando lo seleccionas o das clic,pero si no le doy me arroja el siguiente error "referencia a objecto no establecida como instanacia de un objecto"